# When I shift double click to move all of one item in Minecraft it doesn't work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I pick up an item, hover over another one of that item in a chest. Double click and it shows it goin into my inventory and then goes back into the chest? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: 1. Are you in Spectator mode? 2. Try going to the main menu and back into the world. 3. Are you playing on a server? If yes, did you perform the usual connection checks? Do other things in the game work, like mining a block and picking up its item?

Comment: Im in survival. On a server. With 110 ping. Connection is smooth. mining and placing blocks is fine.

Comment: Does the same happen in Singleplayer or a local server? 110ms ping is not the greatest, but shouldn't lead to that big of a problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be shift and single click to move a stack?

Answer (score -1):

For some reasons, servers might disable this to prevent overpowered grabs. For  example, if there's a factions server and you find a base with lots of tnt, they disable it so that your raid isn't ridiculously insane.